# How to store id in individual string

Tags: android, button

I am trying to get id as per checkbox selection,using model class,but i want to store single id in single string,user select checkbox and then click on button,on buttons click i user will get ids in string.but its not working following is my code can any one help me with that?

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String data = "";

            tet=new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
                 singleStudent = aList.get(i);
                if (singleStudent.isselected() == true) {
                    data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.getPOOJA_LISTING_ID().toString();


                    tet.add(singleStudent.getPOOJA_LISTING_ID());

                    System.out.println("firstid" + tet);
                }
            }

            try {
                for(int j=0; j<tet.size(); j++)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(PoojaSelection.this,
                            "Selected Pooja: \n" + tet.get(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    String oneid=tet.get(0);
                    String secid=tet.get(1);
                    String thirdid=tet.get(2);
                    String fourthid=tet.get(3);
                    String fifthid=tet.get(4);
                    System.out.println("tetaray" + oneid+secid+thirdid+fourthid+fifthid);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }



        }
```

Comment: Show the error please.what is exactly not working

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

on this line String fourthid=tet.get(3);

Comment: so that i added try catch,so eror is gone but logcat shows nothing

Comment: Tjat is because your `aList` length is 3 and you are trying to get the fourth elementos which doesnt exista.please show how do you create your `aList`

Comment: First check the tet.size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it as... you are accessing the list on the basis of your index(like.. 1,2,3) not on list's loop index (like get(j))..

```
String oneid="",secid="", thirdid="" ,fourthid="", fifthid="";

for(int j=0; j<tet.size(); j++)
{
    Toast.makeText(PoojaSelection.this,
            "Selected Pooja: \n" + tet.get(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    if(0==j){
        oneid=tet.get(j);
    }else if(1==j){
        secid=tet.get(j);
    }else if(2==j){
        thirdid=tet.get(j);
    }else if(3==j){
        fourthid=tet.get(j);
    }else if(4==j){
        fifthid=tet.get(j);
    } 
}

Log.e("All strings ", ""+ oneid+" , "+secid+" , "+thirdid+" , "+fourthid+" , "+fifthid);
```

Comment: i am getting this in my logcate

31152-31152/com.example.india.demosss I/System.out﹕ tet1
02-27 12:09:37.627  31152-31152/com.example.india.demosss I/System.out﹕ tet2

Comment: but can you tell if i want to store in individual string

Comment: but where is the string in your code.. you are adding ids in your list ?

Comment: yes in my question i used five string as you can see,so i want to store individual id in string..is itpossibel?

Comment: but do you know how much ids will be selected.. they can be more than your variables or only one ...

Comment: only 5 checkbox user can select so it means only 5 id will be there,thats why i use five diff strings

Comment: what in case of less than five..?

Comment: in that case you can use HashMap to store the values in key value pair..
`HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>()`
store it as
`map.put(id, your string data);`
get it as
`String value = map.get(id);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104707/discussion-between-jolly-and-sourabh-bans).

Answer (score 1):

The IndexOutOfBoundsException s given because you are trying to retrieve an item with `tet.get(index)` without knowing if `tet.size()` is as big as index.

This meaning for example trying `tet.get(4);` while `tet.size()`is equal to 3.
This can solve your problem:

```
String ids = "";
String secondId;
for(int j=0; j<tet.size(); j++) {
                    Toast.makeText(PoojaSelection.this,
                            "Selected Pooja: \n" + tet.get(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    id=id+tet.get(j);

                     //only log the id string after looping all tet
                    if(j==tet.size()-1){
                       Log.d("id","tetaray: " + id +" ");
                    }
                    // edit: save second id
                    if(j==2){
                       Log.d("Second","Second id " + j );
                       secondId=""+j;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: but i am trying to store id in different and individual string

Comment: right now if select two check box,and then click on button,and in my logcat it shows
D/id﹕ tetaray: 12

Comment: can you tell what if i want to store my second selected id in another string??

Comment: it shows incompitable types secondId=j..and i used valueof is it right?

Comment: i select two checkbox and it shows D/id﹕ tetaray: 12..i think no change